# How to seek with avformat_seek_file() but only if the seek jumps forward?

Tags: c, h.264, decoding, libavcodec, libavformat

I am currently writing a program that is decoding a video file and outputting certain frames to images. I have a simple technique for speeding up which entails using `avformat_seek_file` to seek forward in the file to the nearest keyframe before an image, I then decode to the desired image and output is as a jpeg file. The issue I'm having is that, sometimes, when I call `avformat_seek_file` to jump to a keyframe it will take me backward in time to the last keyframe.

the issue is, I've already decoded to the point where I'm at before I call the seek function, which means that I don't need to jump back to a keyframe, it would be quicker for me to  just continue decoding from the point I'm currently at until I reach the desired image.

So my question is, how can I either

1. Give some flag or option to `avformat_seek_file` that tells it not to seek backwards, only seek from my current `pts` onward
2. Detect that `avformat_seek_file` will attempt to seek backwards, and then setup the logic in my own code to skip the call to the seek function and instead just continue decoding from my current location.

I guess one way I could do this is to get a list of the frame numbers of all keyframes in the file before I do any decoding, then do some sort of lookup to see if there is a keyframe between my current position and the desired frame. If there is, `avformat_seek_file()`, if there isn't, don't seek.

Thanks