# avio_tell() return value doesn't change after avformat_seek_file()

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavformat

I have a C++ program that seeks into a video file.

The C++ code looks like the following:

```
int64_t before = avio_tell(formatContext);
int status = avformat_seek_file(formatContext, streamIndex, INT64_MIN, desiredPts, 
desiredPts, 0);
CHECK_EQ(status, 0);
avio_flush(formatContext->pb);
int64_t after = avio_tell(formatContext);

std::cout << "before=" << before << " after=" << after << std::endl;
```

The seek is successful. However, before and after are the exact same value.

In fact from my testing it seems like `avio_tell()` only returns a different value after `avformat_read_frame()`.

The underlying problem I am trying to solve is very similar to this: [How to seek with avformat_seek_file() but only if the seek jumps forward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338115/how-to-seek-with-avformat-seek-file-but-only-if-the-seek-jumps-forward)

My strategy was going to be:

1. Get the position using `avio_tell()`
2. Seek using `avformat_seek_file()`
3. Get the new position using `avio_tell()`. If it seeked backwards, undo the seek by doing a manual seek to the position from (1).

But this strategy doesn't work because `avio_tell()` doesn't change its return value after `avformat_seek_file()`.

Any input would be appreciated.